# Clearing screen in LibGDX

Tags: opengl, libgdx

Why do we need to clear screen every frame with using

```
@Override
public void render() {

    Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glClearColor( 1, 0, 0, 1 );
    Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glClear( GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT |  GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    // scene render code...

}
```

Isn't enough just to redraw a background again and then other elements on top?

Comment: The glClear method overdraws the area wit hthe given glClearColor (https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glClear.xml). It is just to make sure, that the previous frame does not affect the current one. If you are sure, that your background fills the whole area, with full opacity, i guess you don't need to call that function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Telling OpenGL to clear the screen lets it know that it does not need to preserve the image from the last frame. OpenGL ES is designed to redraw the screen from scratch for each frame, so if you don't clear the screen, it assumes you want to keep all the data from the last frame and has to waste time copying the old image to the new frame.

You don't have to call `glClearColor` every frame. It just changes the setting for the color that will be used when clearing the color buffer.

Comment: Also, if you don't clear the depth buffer (as is done in the question), previous depth values might cause unexpected effects.